# Executing scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d with root permission

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I want to execute a script along with initialising the DB schema when I spawn the mariadb image.
I've placed these files under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

The schema initialisation is working as expected

The shell script contains `apt-get install` instructions, which results with the below error

> Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you
>   root?

Performing a `whoami` within the script gave me the output as `mysql`, which explains the script is being run as the user 'mysql' and not as 'root'.

Is there any way I can run this script as root ?

Comment: If you need to install additional software then doing it via a Dockerfile is better.  (It’d be annoying if you needed to restart your database and couldn’t because your Internet connection was broken.)

Comment: My initial attempt was to install it via a Dockerfile.
Performing a CMD to start mysql service resulted in another issue in which the container exits after 20 seconds since it was unable to start mysql service.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mariadb
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```